How to implement real-time Speech-to-Text with Angular, ASP.NET Core Web API, and Microsoft Azure Speech Service?
I am trying to build a real-time speech-to-text web application using Microsoft Azure Speech Service. Currently, I am recording the user's voice using MediaRecorder, and after the user finishes the recording, I send it to the backend for conversion to text.
However, I cannot find a complete example in Microsoft's documentation on how to collect the user's voice in real-time from the browser and send it to my backend via WebSocket.
This is my Angular code:
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import * as WavEncoder from 'wav-encoder';
import { AdminService } from '../admin.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-audio-recorder',
  templateUrl: './audio-recorder.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./audio-recorder.component.css']
})
export class AudioRecorderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private mediaRecorder: MediaRecorder;
  private audioChunks: Blob[] = [];
  audioUrl: SafeUrl;
  isRecording = false;
  isLoading = false;
  transcript: {
    text: string,
    duration: string
  } = { text: '', duration: '' }

  constructor(
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private adminService: AdminService,
    private ngZone: NgZone) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
      .then(stream => {
        this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = event => {
          if (event.data.size > 0) {
            this.audioChunks.push(event.data);
          }
        };

        this.mediaRecorder.onstop = async () => {
          const audioBlob = new Blob(this.audioChunks, { type: 'audio/webm' });
          const arrayBuffer = await audioBlob.arrayBuffer();
          const audioBuffer = await this.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer);
          const wavBlob = await this.convertToWav(audioBuffer);
          const audioURL = URL.createObjectURL(wavBlob);
          this.ngZone.run(() => {
            this.audioUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(audioURL);
          });
          this.ngZone.run(() => {
            this.isLoading = true;
          });
          this.adminService.transcriptFile(wavBlob, "file")
            .subscribe({
              next: (data) => {
                this.ngZone.run(() => {
                  this.transcript.text = data
                  this.isLoading = false
                });
              },
              error: (err) => {
                console.error(err)
                this.isLoading = false
              }
            })
          this.audioChunks = [];
        };
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error accessing microphone:', error);
      });
  }

  startRecording() {
    if (this.mediaRecorder && this.mediaRecorder.state !== 'recording') {
      this.isRecording = true
      this.mediaRecorder.start();
    } else {
      console.warn('MediaRecorder is not available or already recording');
    }
  }

  stopRecording() {
    if (this.mediaRecorder && this.mediaRecorder.state === 'recording') {
      this.isRecording = false
      this.mediaRecorder.stop();
    } else {
      console.warn('MediaRecorder is not recording');
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.audioUrl) {
      URL.revokeObjectURL(this.audioUrl as string);
    }
  }

  // Helper function to decode audio data
  private async decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer: ArrayBuffer): Promise<AudioBuffer> {
    const audioContext = new AudioContext();
    return await audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer);
  }

  // Helper function to convert AudioBuffer to WAV format
  private async convertToWav(audioBuffer: AudioBuffer): Promise<Blob> {
    const wavData = await WavEncoder.encode({
      sampleRate: 16000, // 16 kHz
      bitDepth: 16, // 16 bits
      channelData: [
        this.downsampleBuffer(audioBuffer.getChannelData(0), audioBuffer.sampleRate, 16000)
      ]
    });
    return new Blob([wavData], { type: 'audio/wav' });
  }

  // Helper function to downsample audio buffer
  private downsampleBuffer(buffer: Float32Array, sampleRate: number, targetRate: number): Float32Array {
    if (sampleRate === targetRate) {
      return buffer;
    }
    const sampleRateRatio = sampleRate / targetRate;
    const newLength = Math.round(buffer.length / sampleRateRatio);
    const result = new Float32Array(newLength);
    let offsetResult = 0;
    let offsetBuffer = 0;
    while (offsetResult < result.length) {
      const nextOffsetBuffer = Math.round((offsetResult + 1) * sampleRateRatio);
      let accum = 0, count = 0;
      for (let i = offsetBuffer; i < nextOffsetBuffer && i < buffer.length; i++) {
        accum += buffer[i];
        count++;
      }
      result[offsetResult] = accum / count;
      offsetResult++;
      offsetBuffer = nextOffsetBuffer;
    }
    return result;
  }
}


and Here is My c# code:
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AudioController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost("Transcript")]
        public async Task<string> Transcript(IFormFile audioFile)
        {
            ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(audioFile);
            using var audioStream = audioFile.OpenReadStream();
            Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            var audioKey = "...";
            var audioRegion = "...";
            using var fileStream = audioFile.OpenReadStream();
            var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(audioKey, audioRegion);
            byte[] audioData;
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await audioFile.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                audioData = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
            byte channels = 1;
            byte bitsPerSample = 16;
            uint samplesPerSecond = 16000; // or 8000 based on your audio file's sample rate
            var audioFormat = AudioStreamFormat.GetWaveFormatPCM(samplesPerSecond, bitsPerSample, channels);
            var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromStreamInput(new BytesAudioStream(audioData), audioFormat);
            speechConfig.SpeechRecognitionLanguage = "ar-SA";
            var autoDetectSourceLanguageConfig =
                    AutoDetectSourceLanguageConfig.FromLanguages(["ar-SA"]);
            var speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, autoDetectSourceLanguageConfig, audioConfig);
            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var speechRecognitionResult = await speechRecognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync();
            stopwatch.Stop();
            var duration = stopwatch.Elapsed;
            return speechRecognitionResult.Text;
        }
    }

    public class BytesAudioStream(byte[] audioData) : PullAudioInputStreamCallback
    {
        private readonly MemoryStream memoryStream = new(audioData);
        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, uint size)
        {
            return memoryStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)size);
        }
        public override void Close()
        {
            memoryStream.Close();
        }
    }```


Can you share your GitHub repo or complete code in the question?

@DasariKamali, Sorry, the repo is private. This code is part of a large project for the company I work for.

Can you confirm this, are you saving the audio to a .wav file from Frontend with Angular in the browser and using that .wav file in the Backend to convert the speech to text?

@DasariKamali, Yes, as you can see, I am using the convertToWav in the Frontend method and it works fine. However, this is not what I am looking for. I need a real-time speech-to-text solution where the text appears immediately in the browser while the user is speaking into their microphone. An example of what I’m looking for can be found here: Azure Speech-to-Text Tool

@DasariKamali, It is working on my side, but try this link https://speech.microsoft.com/portal/speechtotexttool
or you can go to https://speech.microsoft.com/portal -> Real-time speech to text -> Try out Real-time speech to text

we call start voice recognition in order to run service until it’s asked to stop service. Now that we can obtain captions and translations from the Cognitive Services Speech SDK, we need to broadcast that information to all viewers who are connected to SignalR Service via WebSocket so that they can display captions in real-time.

and the topic will be covered in Upcoming updated

Here's a full example of how you can implement a real-time speech-to-text solution using Azure Speech SDK in an Angular
Install the Azure Speech SDK
npm install microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk


we call start voice recognition in order to run service until it’s asked to stop service. Now that we can obtain captions and translations from the Cognitive Services Speech SDK, we need to broadcast that information to all viewers who are connected to SignalR Service via WebSocket so that they can display captions in real-time   and the topic will be covered in Upcoming  updated.

Ensure you have the Azure Speech Service subscription key and region. Add these to your environment configuration.
Generate a new service
ng g service speech-recognition


Update src/app/speech-recognition.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as SpeechSDK from 'microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SpeechRecognitionService {
  private _recognizer: SpeechSDK.TranslationRecognizer;
  private _speechConfig: SpeechSDK.SpeechTranslationConfig;
  private _audioConfig: SpeechSDK.AudioConfig;
  hasRecognitionStarted = false;
  speechRecognitionResult = new Subject<any>();
  speechRecognitionLanguage: string = 'en-US';

  constructor() { }

  initRecognition() {
    this._audioConfig = SpeechSDK.AudioConfig.fromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
    this._speechConfig = SpeechSDK.SpeechTranslationConfig.fromSubscription(environment.key, environment.region);
    this._speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = this.speechRecognitionLanguage;
    this._recognizer = new SpeechSDK.TranslationRecognizer(this._speechConfig, this._audioConfig);

    this._recognizer.recognized = (s, e) => this.handleRecognizedResponse(e);
    this._recognizer.canceled = (s, e) => this.handleCanceled(e);
  }

  startContinuousRecognition() {
    try {
      this._recognizer.startContinuousRecognitionAsync(() => {
        console.log('Recognition started');
        this.hasRecognitionStarted = true;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Error', e);
    }
  }

  stopRecognition() {
    this._recognizer.stopContinuousRecognitionAsync(() => {
      this._recognizer.close();
      this.hasRecognitionStarted = false;
    });
  }

  private handleRecognizedResponse(e: SpeechSDK.RecognitionEventArgs) {
    this.speechRecognitionResult.next({ isFinal: true, result: e.result.text });
  }

  private handleCanceled(e: SpeechSDK.CancellationDetails) {
    console.error("Error", e);
  }
}




Generate a new component:
ng g component speech-recognition

Update src/app/speech-recognition/speech-recognition.component.html:
<h1 class="text-center container-heading">Speech To Text Conversion</h1>
<div id="toolbar">
    <button mat-mini-fab (click)="onStart()" *ngIf="!speechHasStarted" color="primary"
        matTooltip="Click on the microphone to start" matTooltipShowDelay="1000">
        <mat-icon>mic_off</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <button mat-mini-fab (click)="onStop()" *ngIf="speechHasStarted" color="warn"
        matTooltip="Click on the microphone to stop" matTooltipShowDelay="1000">
        <mat-icon>mic</mat-icon>
    </button>
     
    <button mat-mini-fab color="warn" [disabled]="!hasContent || speechHasStarted" (click)="onClearContent()"
        matTooltip="Clear transcript" matTooltipShowDelay="1000">
        <mat-icon>clear_all</mat-icon>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="text-center">Click on the microphone icon and begin speaking for as long as you like.</div>
<div class="ConversationContainer">
    <div class="transcriptContainer">
        <div class="text-center">Transcript</div>
        <div #transcriptContainer class="transcript">{{transcript}}</div>
    </div>
</div>

Update src/app/speech-recognition/speech-recognition.component.ts:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SpeechRecognitionService } from '../speech-recognition.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-speech-recognition',
  templateUrl: './speech-recognition.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./speech-recognition.component.css']
})
export class SpeechRecognitionComponent implements OnInit {
  speechHasStarted = false;
  transcript: string = '';
  hasContent: boolean = false;

  constructor(private speechRecognitionService: SpeechRecognitionService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.speechRecognitionService.speechRecognitionResult.subscribe(result => {
      this.transcript += result.result + ' ';
      this.hasContent = true;
    });
  }

  onStart() {
    this.speechRecognitionService.initRecognition();
    this.speechRecognitionService.startContinuousRecognition();
    this.speechHasStarted = true;
  }

  onStop() {
    this.speechRecognitionService.stopRecognition();
    this.speechHasStarted = false;
  }

  onClearContent() {
    this.transcript = '';
    this.hasContent = false;
  }
}








